# Why is there such a big difference with respect to runtime between using list and set in python?

Tags: python, data-structures

I was solving a problem of leetcode (Problem No. 260, title: Single Number III) which outputs the elements of the input list that appear only once. The input list consists of only elements that either appears only once or exactly twice. Here is the link to the problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/single-number-iii/

I solved this problem using the following code:

```
from typing import List
class Solution:
    def singleNumber(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[int]:
        res = []
        for num in nums:
            if num in res:
                res.remove(num)
            else:
                res.append(num)
        return res

sol = Solution()
print(sol.singleNumber([1,2,1,3,2,5]))
```

I got the correct result which is [3, 5] and this solution is all correct. But I had a runtime measured by leetcode to be 960ms when I submitted it.

I found one solution in the discussion section which in my view only changed the data structure of the variable where the occurrence of numbers was stored ("res" in my solution and "m" in the solution I found). It used set and I used list.
The solution looks like this:

```
from typing import List
class Solution:
    def singleNumber(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[int]:
        m = set()
        for i in nums:
            if i in m:
                m.remove(i)
            else:
                m.add(i)
        return list(m)

sol = Solution()
print(sol.singleNumber([1,2,1,3,2,5]))
```

I submitted this solution to test its runtime and it gave me a performance of 56 ms. I wonder why there is such a big difference in runtime compared with my solution? In my view, the logic we used are basically the same. Is there anything inside these two data structures that caused this difference?

Any hint will be nice, thanks in advance!

Comment: Searching a list is O(n), searching a set is O(1).

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: Sets use hashing, lists are sequential searching.

Comment: Ah, I see. That's the thing. Thanks!